# Why such a variety of letters before final я?

Tags: грамматика, правописание

I am puzzled by the number of different letters that  can be found before a final *я*, for example:

> до свидания, синяя, третья,...

That last one is especially puzzling since we write

> третий

without a *ь*.

Is there a difference in pronunciation?
If pronunciation is not the reason, is there a general rule or a grammatical or a historical explanation?

Comment: Why does я seem unusual to you in this way? There are words ending in e with various letters right before them and it never seemed like a peculiar feature to me, e.g., многообразие, сжимающее, Башелье, Диксмье, Картье, Навье, Фурье,...

Comment: @KCd: I want to know if these words are homophones. And, if they are, why they are written differently. Of course, there might be no reasonable  answer, but if by luck there **is** a good answer it would be a satisfying linguistic information and would help me memorize the different spellings. And, indeed, I'm puzzled by words ending in  е too: this might become  another question :-)

Comment: On a related note, unstressed o and a are pronounced the same. I once saw a student in the US who spoke Russian fluently but never learned to read or write it who wrote молоко as малако. I was shocked. A better way to learn spelling than by how words sound is by making distinctions based on the *case* being used. For instance, masculine and neuter nouns often end in -a in genitive singular, like пучок --> пучка. That's why it "makes sense" to see многообразие --> многообразия or отображение --> отображения when passing from nominative to genitive (singular), since -я is playing a role like -а.

Comment: Unstressed о and а are not necessarily pronounced the same: собака is pronounced [sɐbákə]. The unstressed vowel *а* can also be pronounced [ɪ] as in часы.

Comment: Fair enough.  There are *some* situations when they are pronounced the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**свидание → свидания** is a perfectly regular form. It is a noun, not an adjective. Сомнение → сомнения, решение→решения, раздумье→раздумья, вычисление→вычисления, небытие→небытия. You just keep the same stem as in Nominative. Not so with any formation where you need to *remove the vowel*. Then you replace Ь with И (obviously, you cannot leave "ьй" dangling at the end of the word):

- раздумье→раздумий
- колдунья→колдуний

**In Russian adjectives like *синий*** you have a regular pattern with ый(ой)/ий - ая/яя, ое/ее, ые/ие in the Nominative:

- большой/длинный/синий кот (-ой is if the adjective has an unlimate stress)
- большая/длинная/синяя кошка
- большое/длинное/синее нечто
- большие/длинные/синие кошки

(note that velars **к, г, х** cannot have **ы** after them, so they always have **и**: короткий-короткая-короткое-короткие)

Actually, these unstressed -ия, -яя -ее are pronounced identical or almost identical in speech. However, some actors and other professional voices ***may** enunciate them a bit more clearly (which is not in fact the current norm but still used, especially in station announcements where they may really want you to hear that "Окское" ends in -ое, not -ая)

**with третья**, I suppose, it is just a historical development. It affects pronunciation and makes it easier (to just omit the unnecessary vowel). That does not affect adjectives.

Historically both **Ъ** and **Ь** denoted a short vowel ([ə]-like and  [i]-like). It explains why in poetry -ие and -ье are often used interchangeably, less so in speech (which conforms more to how a speaker is used to pronounce the words, not to some rhytm).

It also explains formation of **колдунья → колдуний**: before a liquid Й and a vowel the short sound was eliminated but before a final consonant the language preferred to make it longer and convert to a normal И instead ("колдуньй" is really hard to pronounce).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How does the *ь* affect the pronunciation of *третья* ? It would be soft anyway, wouldn't it ?

Comment: Of course. Here it is straightforward: [`tr'et'jə]. Which is not always the case because in some consonant clusters "softness" propagates to the first consonant as well (in "песня" both **с** and **н** are palatilized; happened in a lot more clusters in the early 20th century Russian, not so much today).

Comment: By the way, I checked the reverse dictionary to look up other adjectives to test a though I had... I were right. You see, in Russian there are VERY FEW adjectives that add in "рий", "тий", "чий", "сий". Mostly these are the ones that denote a link to some person or animal (лисий, сучий). They use -ья in feminine Nominative. **-чий** has -ая variants for non-derived adjectives (жгучий) but -тий has none, and I suppose all of them just drop the vowel no matter the origin. Probably, -чий is a special case...